# What are the potential causes for slow Content Download Time from ASP.NET Core API hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: Content Download at 1.8 mins]

The attached image shows a download of 1.5mb of JSON from a ASP.NET Core(1.0.0) Web API controller hosted under IIS. I am struggling to debug where all this time is going. Does anyone have suggestions of the potential cause of this?

On localhost under kestrel it takes 4.5 seconds.
On localhost under IIS it takes 13 seconds.

Potentially looking more like an infrastructure constraint?

Comment: Information about the env you are noticing this in might be helpful.

Comment: 4.5 Secs on localhost is also bad ... shouldn't take that long for 1.5MB on localhost ... how long does it take to actually process this information?

Comment: Im aware but a good proportion of this is db query time so im not worried about this. IT is on a Windows 2012 server, IIS 8.5, hosted on an Enterprise network. The servers resources aren't an issues - RAM usually at 30% of 12Gb, CPU around 5% with spikes now and again.

Comment: do you have response compression enabled?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2